# VBA - Connect to an Access Database via Citirx

Tags: vba, database-connection, connection-string, citrix

I have an access database file that is located on our server. This file is used by an Excel VBA code, however user who don't have a VPN will not be able to access the directory and the database file.

I want to solver this problem using Citrix (probably File Explorer App). I can easily use the Citrix app to access the database file manually, however I am trying to figure out how I can make VBA use a connection through Citirx to access the same file.

Assume that the address through which I get access to the data base in VBA is like:

`strSBPath=\\MyServer.com\Directory1\Directory2\MyDB.accdb`

I use an ADO connection between Excel and Access file on the server:

`conn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strDBPath & ";"`

Now I need to define a new connection that utulizes Citrix rather than an ADO connection.
I am new to Citirx so I have no idea how to define this connection. Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the MDB or accdb file to citrix.

Comment: in that case, what would be the connection between the Excel file and Citrix?